# Solve summation for variable that is in upper limit and summation

Tags: summation

I don't remember how to solve these, but I hope someone can refresh my memory.  I have the following equation, how can I solve for t?

$$50000 = \sum_{i=0}^{12t} 1.004^{12(t - i/12)}$$

EDIT: if it helps at all, expands out to $$50000 = 1.04^{12t} + 1.04^{12(t-1/12)} + 1.04^{12(t-2/12)} + .... + 1$$

Comment: Can you find a geometric series  in there?

Comment: Normally, I input t in order to find the 50000, but now I am trying to do it in reverse, given the 50000, find t

Comment: Numerically, $t=110.623...$

Comment: Second hint to support @GEdgar's one: Show that $$1.04^{12t} + 1.04^{12(t-1/12)} + 1.04^{12(t-2/12)} + \cdots + 1$$ is actually $$1.04^{12t} + 1.04^{12t-1} + 1.04^{12t-2} + \cdots + 1$$ that is, with $r=1.04$, $$\sum_{i=0}^{12t}r^i=\frac{r^{12t+1}-1}{r-1},$$ hence...

Comment: so $t$ won't be an integer as it seems, how should your sum then actually work?

Comment: @user190080 In case your comment is directed at me: 1. please use @, 2. I have no idea what you are talking about (of course $12t$ should be an integer).

Comment: @Did no, the comment was meant to address the OP...to clarify: if you solve it the way you did and as in the accepted answer, you get a non-integer $t$, but this of course means that the sum is sort of not well defined if you just plug in $t$. so it won't work out as the OP thought (like the last term of summation is $1$) and in the long run, the equality simply doesn't hold for any integer $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
50000 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{12t} 1.004^{12(t - i/12)}
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{12t} 1.004^{12t - i}
\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{12t} 1.004^k\qquad\text{where $k=12t-i$}
\\
&=\frac{1.004^{12t+1}-1}{1.004-1}
\\
1.004^{12t+1}&=201
\\
t&=\frac 1{12}\left(\frac{\ln 201}{\ln1.004}-1\right)=110.62\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: amazing, thanks!